# Is it possible to use regular expressions to camelize/underscore strings?

Tags: regex, perl, sublimetext

Is it possible to use nothing but Regular Expressions to convert strings like "hello_world" into "HelloWorld" and back?

I'm asking because I often need to create snippets for Sublime Text that automatically fills in "class_name" somewhere when I type "ClassName" somewhere else. I can only use [perl-style regular expressions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) for this purpose.

Comment: To translate `a` to `A` you would need some kind of callback function - and that's not available in "pure" RegEx AFAIK.

Comment: +1 @CBroe. Here's a (more complex) example in ruby: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/feaa6e2048fe86bcf07e967d6e47b865e42e055b/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L68

Comment: @CBroe [Perl supports this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) without requiring a callback.

Comment: If you can use 2 substitutions, `s/([A-Z])/_\l$1/g` and `s/^_//` can  convert "HelloWorld" to "hello_world"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using perl regular expression:

**hello_world -> HelloWorld**

```
s/(_|\b)([a-z])/\u\2/g;
```

- `\b`: Match at boundary (space, start of string, punctuation mark, ..)
- `[a-z]`: lowercase alphabet
- `\u`: make uppercase for next character
- `\2`: group 2 (first lowercase character)
- `(_|\b)` -> group 1
- `([a-z])` -> group2

**HelloWorld -> hello_world**

```
s/([A-Z][a-z]+|[a-z]+)([A-Z])/\l\1_\l\2/g;
```

- *Does not work for `Hello`.*
- If you can use two substitutions, use `s/([A-Z])/_\l\1/g;` followed by `s/^_//;`

Comment: If you could expand the expression and explain all the elements, I'll mark the answer as accepted right away :)

Comment: @Codemonkey, added explanation. Sorry for poor English.

Comment: @Codemonkey, I'm finding way for reverse direction.

Comment: Reverse is something like `([a-z])([A-Z])` -> `\1_\l\2`

Comment: @Rawling, With that expression, the very first character remain uppercase.

Comment: Group 1 is unnecessary, i.e. you can write `(_|\b)` as `[_\b]`.

Comment: @doubleDown, `\b` inside `[]` is interpreted as `\x08`(BS).

Comment: @Codemonkey, I'm still trying to find a way ;)